# How our test in this world is fair

Tags: judgements

I understand our life here is a test, but I don't understand how it's going to be fair for everyone. I will tell you a real-life situation:

Tom and tim are twin brothers. Both of them lived a bad life by doing murder theft and all the evil activities until they reach 25 years old and tom died in an accident. I assume by the evil he did in his life he is going to be in hell. Now after tom died tim becomes Muslim and his life is changed. He prayed for mercy and only did good until he died later at the age of 60. So here how their test going to be fair. If somehow tim is going to heaven I am sure tom is going to complain. I know Allah knows what's best and if he lived long what it's going to be, but still he deserve a chance that tim had to be a fair test.

Answer (score 0):

It's written in the Qu'ran that no soul is given a test that it cannot bear.

There's also a tradition that there are two angels, one of whom that records all the good deeds and the other, all the bad deeds.

Allah knows not only a man or a woman's  outward deeds but also their inward self. Even if they do not open their soul to Allah.

Answer (score 0):

Theory:     Tom: Bad     Tim: Good

Firstly, Allah (God) who knows everything, is aware that Tim has the potential of repentance to be changed in a good person, thus He always realizes the best for us; Whereas He also knows Tom (albeit being Twin) wouldn't repent ... Since there is no guarantee that two persons (twin) to be treatmently the same. I myself knows several twins with many differences in behavior and ... so, necessarily it is not a correct theory to expect that two twins ought to have the same fate.

Allah, the kindest, is aware that if the ones such as Tom will keep on in their bad way even if they live more 1000 years. Thus, it is not unfair, especially when we know that the judge in the fairest.

Comment: then it seems that life is no test at all.